# Broken streaming URLs for Soundcloud API

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

I'm trying to play songs from the soundcloud api and there are a few that are not working. When I try to play the streaming url with my client id attached to it I get the following error in my console.

```
rack_24: Using HTML5 soundmanager2-jsmin.js?body=1:33
soundManager.stopAll() soundmanager2-jsmin.js?body=1:33
track_24: play(): Attempting to load soundmanager2-jsmin.js?body=1:33
track_24: load (http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/104284258/stream?client_id=92a7061920c8cc8ab97038d2eba985cf) soundmanager2-jsmin.js?body=1:33
track_24: waiting soundmanager2-jsmin.js?body=1:33
track_24: loadstart soundmanager2-jsmin.js?body=1:33
track_24: HTML5 error, code 4 soundmanager2-jsmin.js?body=1:33
track_24: Failed to load / invalid sound? Zero-length duration reported. (http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/104284258/stream?client_id=92a7061920c8cc8ab97038d2eba985cf)
```

If I click on the url it just takes me to a blank page. However if I click on a working url it  will take me to an mp3 stream. Any ideas why this is happening? The song I am trying to play is [Drake ~ Hold On, We're Going Home feat. Majid Jordan](https://soundcloud.com/g3tfamiliar/hold-on-were-going-home-ft)

I have more examples if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue with some songs for few months now.  If you use Soundcloud javascript SDK, problem seems to be resolved when you use new 2.0 sdk that became official on July 1st

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/javascript-sdk-2